# Random matrix: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, int, tuples

I am trying to generate a matrix with which is mxn and contains random numbers. I have produced the following code, but am confused by the error I am receiving. Here is the code I am using:

```
class MP:
def __init__(self,
          mSize, nSize
             ):
    self.mSize=mSize,
    self.nSize=nSize

def RMatrix(param):
  assert isinstance(param, MP)
  m = int(param.mSize)
  n = int(param.nSize)
  A=np.random.rand(m,n)
  return (np.matrix(A))
```

I am receiving the error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'. Why are the values being passed as tuple? What is going on here and how can I fix this?

Comment: what is "param" suppose to be? What kind of input is param?

Comment: It is an instance of the class. you can interchange Self and param as you wish. Error is still the same if I type in either Self or param. Though I am very new to python, so I could be wrong? Anyone out there with more python OOP knowledge please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Do I need to unpack the tuple somehow???

Comment: @CuriousPython - You are correct that you _can_ change the name of `self`. However, I would advise against it, as it can cause confusion when other people (or yourself at a later date) read the code.

Comment: Can you please show us how you create the instance of MP? The problem is likely there.

Comment: MC= Matrix_Calculations.MP(mSize=10,nSize=10) [new line here in code]

      Matrix_Calculations.RMatrix(MC)

Comment: Ok it seems I was wrong. Abhijit found the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. You have an comma in your init (at self.mSize=mSize**,**) . Remove that and your code will work fine.

```
import numpy as np
class MP:
    def __init__(self,
              mSize, nSize
                 ):
        self.mSize=mSize
        self.nSize=nSize

    def RMatrix(param):
      assert isinstance(param, MP)
      m = int(param.mSize)
      n = int(param.nSize)
      A=np.random.rand(m,n)
      return (np.matrix(A))

x=MP(3,3)
print x.RMatrix()
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.88170563  0.56061723  0.71311863]
 [ 0.3550273   0.83179011  0.10337231]
 [ 0.43324567  0.52177816  0.04648175]]
```